# How to deal with very simple questions that garner downvotes?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, question-quality

With Apple having just released the [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) programming language, there are many new questions flooding in, and some of these might be qualified as general reference (something that's easy to find with a simple glance at the language documentation).

The discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason) would indicate that "**general reference**" has been carefully considered, and rejected as a close reason. However, questions that might be closed as "general reference" (such as [Creating an Objective-C equivalent Getter and Setter in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151197/getter-and-setter-variable-in-swift)) are getting downvotes and close votes (it seems people are resorting to "**unclear what you're asking**" as a replacement for "general reference").

What should we do with these questions? Some options I see:

1. Allow them to be downvoted and deleted naturally, erasing content that is technically welcome on the site.
2. Allow people to close them for reasons that don't really apply ("unclear what you're asking").
3. Aggressively edit the question and the best answer to make a high quality reference for future visitors.

Comment: These are questions from programmers that didn't make it past chapter 5.  And why would they when they can get somebody else to read it for them?  Or type the google query for them?  If *you* didn't learn something from the question then you already know how to vote.  Asking for guidance is a wee bit ironic.

Comment: I don't think "whether or not I personally learned something" is a good way to decide how to vote. ["Voting up is how the community indicates which questions and answers are most useful and appropriate."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: Who the heck is that "community" and how do I unsubscribe?  Vote as you please.

Answer (score 9):

General reference questions in themselves are not an issue, it's *how* and *why* the question was asked that matters more.

Your example might seem obvious to you, but it isn't necessarily obvious to everyone else, and there is no reason why it cannot be asked and answered.

The bigger problem I can see starting to happen is that a bit of a gold rush has kicked off - people have the opportunity to ask basic questions that are going to be seen (and potentially voted on) many times in the future.

Some of these questions may be perceived as trivial and unnecessary and consequently down voted. I would suggest that these questions are kept despite the down votes and tidied up where necessary. If these questions are closed and deleted then they'll eventually be asked again - so keep the original (ignore the down votes - once tidied up these will even out over time).

Comment: "there is no reason why it cannot be asked and answered" — I agree, and yet the question has had several downvotes and close votes already. Most people (who know the answer already) simply see it as an unnecessarily basic question.

Comment: @jtbandes Good point, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't think it's a great argument that bad questions should be kept because otherwise more incarnations of the bad question will be asked.  If the argument is that these questions are not in fact bad, then just stick with that rationale rather than the (IMO flawed) meta argument.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're overlooking something.

The referenced question isn't just basic. It's also *unclear*.

> what does the below Objective-C code is in Swift.

I can't work out what that means. Granted, I don't know much about Swift. I do know it interoperates with Objective-C. But I still have no idea what that means.

If you want people to look well towards basic questions, make them of a high quality. Look towards the many concise-yet-clear examples we have already on the site.

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with interoperability.  It's a code-translation question:  "how to write this Objective-C code in Swift?"

Comment: Exactly. Unclear. I had no idea that that was the question. Seriously, if you can read it *please* rewrite it.

Comment: Done, and lol, I agree it *was* unclear.  But I think it was unclear due merely to a lack of an adequate command of English.  Whether it's in fact a good question for SO even now is a separate matter.

Comment: I think you have me confused with the OP, @jpbandes. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll Yup... sorry.